# c++ add word to file if its not there

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I am making an application to add data but I am trying to add a data check that checks if the specific data being added already exists then it wont add to the file.
Here is what I have but so far its not working, no errors but it just adds the data that already exists:

```
void checklog(const std::string& input){
    ifstream iFile("C:\\Users\\Seann\\Documents\\storedData\\data.txt");
    string line;
    while(getline(iFile, line)){
        if(input!=line){
        iFile.close();
        updateLog(input);}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to any serious answers.

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: Assuming your file has one word per line, this will add the word as soon as it doesn't match the most recent entry read. Your description indicates you only want to add it if *all* entries has no match.

Comment: So you break out of the loop, if you find the first line, that is not equal to input?

Comment: Actually, this will add the word if it doesn't match *every* entry.

Comment: unfortunately I can't show you what my file looks like without making a long list on here, I was going to gyazo it but gyazo is not working for me at the moment.

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way around. Keep checking *until* you find a match. If you did not (`getline` fails), you add the word.

Comment: @dari unfortunately I can't show you what my file looks like without making a long list on here, I was going to gyazo it but gyazo is not working for me at the moment.
I did try adding the iFile.Close(); after the loop but it caused my application to stop responding.

Comment: i tried this too 
while(getline(iFile, line))
 {
  if(input==line){
   iFile.close();}
  else{
   updateLog(input);}
 }

but the same thing happens i have the same data over and over

Comment: That last suggestion checks only one single line.

Comment: @Jongware any chance you could post a code to try and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if ... else` attempt still makes its decision at the first line it reads, and not loop until you found the word.  Try this:

```
void checklog(const std::string& input){
    ifstream iFile("data.txt");
    string line;
    bool found = false; 
    while (!found && getline(iFile, line)){
        if (input == line)
            found = true;
    }
    iFile.close();
    if (found)
        updateLog(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check every line for the word, you should create something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> fileInput;

int i = 0;

while (std::getline(iFile, fileInput[i])
i++;

i = 0;
bool found_string = false;

while (i < input.size())
{
if (string_that_you_wanted_to_compare == fileInput[i])
found_string = true;
}

if (found_string)
{ do whatever }
```

Or something like that.

Comment: okay I tried adding that to my function but it gave me an error.
void checklog(const std::string& input){
 ifstream iFile("C:\\Users\\Seann\\Documents\\storedData\\data.txt");
 std::vector<std::string> fileInput;
 int i = 0;
 while (std::getline(iFile, fileInput[i]){
  i++;}

 i = 0;
 bool found_string = false;
 while (i < fileinput.size())
 {
  if (input == fileInput[i])
   found_string = true;
 }
 if (!found_string){
  updateLog(input);
 }
}

error C2039: 'Update_Click' : is not a member of 'My App::Form1'

Comment: That doesn't sound like the usual C++ error... What is this "Update_Click?"